# Laravel app logging out authenticated user when redirecting (it shouldn't)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have created a method that logs a user into our site via a link from a separate website. We use a token and username to find the user, then use the built in login method to authenticate them (I can confirm this all works as expected).

Here is the function:

```
public function login($username, $token, $redirect)
{
    $accountLogin = AccountLogin::Where('username', $username)
        ->Where('token', $token)
        ->first();

    if ($accountLogin) {
        try {
            Auth::login($accountLogin);
            print_r(Auth::check()) // prints 1.
            header('Location: ' . $redirect);
            exit;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    echo(array(
       'status' => 'error',
       'message' => 'Error logging in'
    ));
}
```

My problem is that the user seems to be logged out after the redirect.

Within the function above I can see the the account is found, and 
`Auth::check()` returns 1 or if I echo out `Auth::User()` then I do get the users info.

We then attempt to do a redirect which should take us to the route passed in as a parameter (you do need to be authenticated for all these routes) but instead I am redirected to the home page and logged out. If I log in from that page then it takes me to the url I wanted to reach originally (so it's like it is remembering where I want to go, but just doesn't recognise that I'm logged in).

Both sites are currently running locally via apache.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Did you extend `Authenticatable` in your `AccountLogin` model?

You could try using the `loginUsingId($id, $remember = false)` function with the user id.

Answer (score 0):

instead of rediricting in this way :

```
header('Location: ' . $redirect);
exit;
```

use this  :

```
return redirect($redirect);
```

Laravel has it's own redirect helper method which you had better use it instead. also redirecting in your way and exit at the end of it, ruins the user id that was stored in session , so it supposed that user is not logged in.